# Adding rows to a databound datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am loading data into a datagridview from a dataset. After loading I need to add new rows to the datagridview.

1. Is there a way to add rows to a databound datagridview

or

1. How can I unbind the datagridview
2. the loaded data remain in the datagridview
3. Add new rows to the datagridview

Comment: Add rows to dataset prior to binding.

Comment: Cannot do that. Its the users choice to add the row

Comment: Users sometimes make bad choices. It is your responsibility as a developer to suggest a different option. If you always follow what users say, you will end up in a maintainability nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

Try using BindingSource like

```
Dim m_Bs as new BindingSource


m_Bs.DataSource = DataSet1.Tables("TableName")
DataGridView1.Datasource = m_Bs
```

And enable adding row on DataGridView1
Any changes From the  Datagridview will reflect on the Dataset.